# Access MLflow Artifacts in Model Registry Using Python

Tags: python, databricks, mlflow

I am looking to access the artifacts of a model registered to the Model Registry in Databricks. However, I want to be able to do this outside of Databricks, using a Python script.

Specifically, I want to be able to access the `feature_spec.yml` shown in the directory structure below,

[image]

I came across this article in the Microsoft docs, but it is not quite clear,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/applications/mlflow/access-hosted-tracking-server

Note that I will probably only have the name of the Model and the Version that I want to access. How can I do this using Python?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.tracking.html#mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient.download_artifacts

import mlflow

mlflow.tracking.MLflowClient().download_artifacts(run_id, "model_packaged/data/feature_store/raw_model/feature_spec.yml")